# Communication from silverlight to winforms via webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to send a JSON string via Winforms application to my Silverlight application.

I have attempted a few times to get it done by exposing my silverlight method using

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
.....
[ScriptableMember]
public void CallMeInSilverlight(string message)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Alert("The form said: " + message);
}
```

in javascript

```
function CallMe(message) {
    var control = document.getElementById('silverlightControl');
    control.Content.Page.CallMeInSilverlight(message);
}
```

But for some reason I can't make this work with the javascript. It just doesn't get called.

in Winforms

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("CallMe", new object[] { "testing 1 2 3" });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It all looks right.  Are you sure your silverlight control id is correct?  Are you getting any JS errors in the web browser?

Comment: Have you set `WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true` ?

Comment: John Koerner: <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%" id="silverlightControl">
ColinE,  IsScriptEnabled does not exist.

Comment: I have tried it again where I placed my "test" method in the DocumentCompleted event instead of straight at the start and it works now after giving a error message first. The error message only tells me "An error has occurred in the script on this page.  Line 56" and some other stuff but not what kind of error. "Unspecified error, code 0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when I build my project, the text page which is created by Silverlight gets over writen.

Since this was the html page to which my webbrowser was posting it's javascript commands, the commands never reached the silverlight control.

After creating a seperate page with the javascript commands it worked perfectly.